# Методы оцифровки нарисованного текста

Tags: текст, распознавание-образов, распознавание-символов

Здравствуйте!

Существуют ли какие-нибудь методы распознавания нарисованного текста? Ведь создано множество различных программ, в том числе и для мобильных платформ, которые, например, распознают нарисованный текст при написании сообщения.

Comment: Единственное что знаю по теме - [java OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/)

Comment: Пример: [A C# Project in Optical Character Recognition (OCR) Using Chain Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160868/A-C-Project-in-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-U).

Comment: В данном случае необходимы именнометодики распознавания, а не библиотеки...но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Пример на нейронных сетях: http://linux.ria.ua/mnist_brain/nnTest.html Исходники:
https://github.com/ApelSYN/mnist_brain

Comment: Методов существует множество, но, как правило, всё завязано на обучении. [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143129/) можно почитать основы и поверхностно понять принцип работы нейросетей в сторону распознавания. Вообще, сейчас существует огромное количество научных работ, статей и т.д. на тему распознавания образов и очень странно, что Вам проще задать вопрос здесь, чем погуглить.

Comment: Что такое нарисованный текст? Приведите пример.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы преобразовать рукопись в текст, потребуется движок распознавания рукописного текста. Обычно подобные движки платные и заточены под конкретный язык. Из бесплатных: [CellWriter](http://risujin.org/cellwriter/cellwriter.pdf) и [Tegaki](http://tegaki.org/) под Linux.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать о методах распознавания, так как все хочется сделать самому. Пользоваться чужим в данном случае неуместно, а тем более еще и платным.